# Euler Project 14 - Longest Collatz sequence in PHP

Tags: php, performance

This is my solution to  [Euler Project Problem 14](https://projecteuler.net/problem=14)

```
<?php
$count = 0 ;
$max = 0;

for($n = 2 ; $n < 1000000 ; $n++){
        while ($n > 1)
        {
            if ($n % 2 == 0 )
            {
                $n = $n/2;

            }
            else
            {
                $n = 3*$n + 1 ;

            }               
            $count += 1;

           if($count > $max )
           {
                $max = $count;
                $final = $n;    
           }
        }
     }
     echo $final;
>?
```

It took so long to run.I looked some other solutions and they were very similar to my code logically,but they were running way too faster than mine.
My question is,what is it that makes my code inefficient? What am I missing here?

Thanks ^^

Comment: This should move to the code-review group; the main SO site is for programming problems.  Without a demonstrated functional problem (e.g. provide a timing analysis for your run), this doesn't quite qualify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is straight forward and unpolished.

You can use dynamic programming in order to improve the runtime (complexity approach).

Let's say you want to compute for 5. You will have :
5 -> 16 -> 8 -> 4 -> 2 -> 1.
But if you do that you will also have computed the value for 8 and 16.
The idea is to store the value that you have already computed in order to save work when you will need them later.

Working on the complexity of an algorithm will be the key of some problems, so better get used to it early.

An other reason why it is slow, is the choice of the language. For example try with C it will run a lot faster.